# Multiple Hall Effect sensors to one input

Tags: sensor

I've done some work in the past with hooking up Hall Effect sensors, e.g. OH090U up to an Arduino. Please note, I do have limited electronics knowledge.

What I would like to know is if it is possible to wire up multiple OH090U components to increase the coverage of detecting a magnetic field over a larger area. Is there a way to tie the digital output across multiple sensors, so that if one or many sensors trigger it just sends one digital output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably you could use one of these CD4072BM96 ([OR gate](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/cd4071b.pdf)), this is logic OR gate. Output will give you one digital high output if any of the inputs is high.

Comment: You forgot to add the link.

Comment: Excellent. Thank you, I've just ordered so OR gates for me to test with.